# Accidentally deleted tomcat `webapps` folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have accidentally deleted the webapps folder in tomcat. I had 2 web applications there deployed as .war files and the default tomcat folder, "Root", "manager", "host-manager", "examples" and "docs".

Since I am on cloud amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu) and I have no use of tomcat manager, can I simply create a new directory manually called webapps and copy and paste the .war files of my projects?

Will this work or is this subjected to break something at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely yes, your apps will be automatically deployed again after some seconds.

Moreover, you can download those `Root`, `manager`, `host-manager`, `examples` and `docs` folders from the tomcat distribution, and copy them into your webapps directory. The **manager** and **host-manager** apps will restart automatically.

Since the configuration to access manager and host-manager is inside `conf/tomcat-users.xml`, it has not been deleted. So the apps will work like previously, without any change.